# Apple Safari and Handheld Browser CSS issues

Tags: css, safari, handheld

I have a problem with the logo on my site, but only in Safari on Apple devices.

This is my site: http://iiointeractive.com/

The big blue "iio" link should be a square. It displays properly in every browser I have tested - including Safari on Windows - but displays as a rectangle in Safari on all Apple devices.

Here is a screenshot of the issue: FILE REMOVED

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id='logo_iio'>
   <a href="/">iio</a>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
//reset
html,body,a,p{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
#logo_iio {
   font-family: 'Agency';
   font-weight: normal;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
   float: left;
}
#logo_wrap a {
   font-size: 80px;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #00baff;
   padding: 0 25px 10px;
}
```

I tried using `line-height` to make the styles consistent, but it didn't influence the height of the blue background. changing `height` doesn't do anything. I can use `padding-top` to fix the display in Safari, but this messes up the styles in all other browsers.

The only solution I can think of is to write a php script to detect the user's OS and browser and load an additional CSS file with a different padding value...

Is there an easier solution?

Comment: I can see that you are not using the reset style `*{border-sizng:border-box; padding:0; marging:0;}`

Comment: I don't like using * - its unnecessary and slows the page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess not.

One update - I found that the problems weren't just on Apple devices, but all handheld devices.

Here's that php script - put it at the end of the `head` element:

```
function getOS() { 

    global $user_agent;
    $os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";
    $os_array       =   array(
                            '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
                            '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                            '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                            '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                            '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                            '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                            '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                            '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                            '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                            '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                            '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                            '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                            '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                            '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                            '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                            '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                            '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                            '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                            '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                            '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                        );
    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value)
        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent))
            $os_platform    =   $value;
    return $os_platform;
}

function getBrowser() {
    global $user_agent;
    $browser        =   "Unknown Browser";
    $browser_array  =   array(
                            '/msie/i'       =>  'Internet Explorer',
                            '/firefox/i'    =>  'Firefox',
                            '/safari/i'     =>  'Safari',
                            '/chrome/i'     =>  'Chrome',
                            '/opera/i'      =>  'Opera',
                            '/netscape/i'   =>  'Netscape',
                            '/maxthon/i'    =>  'Maxthon',
                            '/konqueror/i'  =>  'Konqueror',
                            '/mobile/i'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
                        );
    foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value)
        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) 
            $browser    =   $value;
    return $browser;
}

$OS = getOS();
$browser = getBrowser();
if($browser=='Handheld Browser'
    ||(($OS=='Mac OS X'||$OS=='Mac OS 9'||$OS=='iPhone'||$OS=='iPod'||$OS=='iPad'||$OS=='Mobile')&&($browser=='Safari'))) : ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #logo_wrap a{padding-top:15px !important}
        #message{width:355px}
        #contactForm input{padding-bottom:10px}
        #service h3{margin-bottom: 20px}
    </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```